# Deleting Row from TableView and coreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, tableview, delete-row

I have some problem with deleting rows from a tableView which is filled with coreData objects.

Trying to do this:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

            [self.tableView beginUpdates];

            NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", [managedObject valueForKey:@"original_title"]);
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
            [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

            [self performFetch];       
            [self.tableView endUpdates];       
        }   
    }
```

So, when I click the "Delete" button, the app crashes with the following Log:

```
    *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2872.3/UITableView.m:1254
    2013-08-13 18:39:17.624 RR_proto[1076:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections. 
 The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal 
to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus
 the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'
    *** First throw call stack:
```

I also tried to add the following line after [self.managedObjectContext save:nil]:

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

But the app crashes like before.

One more thing, everytime i start the app again after a crash through delete-action, the cell which should be deleted is really gone!

Would be very nice, if somebody can help. 
I know there are many questions about similar problems and I tried different things from these, without success. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The table view is updated automatically by the fetched results controller delegate
methods when objects are added, deleted or modified.

Therefore, to remove an object, just delete it from the managed object context.
Don't call `beginUpdates`, `endUpdates`, `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` or `performFetch`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is one step in right direction for the solution. Now the App didn´t crash, but the tableview didn´t get updated after delete-action. only if change the view, and come back again, the Tableview will be updated.

Comment: @user2355509: Have you implemented the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods: controllerWillChangeContent, didChangeObject, controllerDidChangeContent, ... as described in the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html ?

Comment: sorry for my unskilled question about this: now I have implemented in ".h" file <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>. Do I have to implement those methods manually, and call them within "if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {"?

Comment: @user2355509: You have to *implement* the methods in your .m file. The NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate documentation has sample code that can more or less be copied into your table view controller.

Comment: OK, I have implemented these methods too, and there is no error in code. But this doesn´t take effect. TableView still didn´t reload, after delete action, only after reload the whole view.

Comment: @user2355509: Are the delegate methods called at all? Perhaps you forgot to assign the fetched results controller's delegate, e.g. `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self`? - If you create a new  iOS project in Xcode using the "Master-Detail Application" template and select "Use Core Data" then you will get a sample app with table view and fetched results controller!

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I forgot self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self; for sure!  Thank you very much!

Comment: that "save" just saved me :)