# Objective C -> Records only delete from table view but not from core data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I use the following code to delete the records from my table view and from core data. But the records are only delete permanent from the table view but not from core data:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [tableView beginUpdates];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedRecordsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        tpAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        self.fetchedRecordsArray = [appDelegate getAllRecords];

        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does an error print out? And what does your core data stack look like? Do you have multiple contexts, or just the one? I see you get all the records from core data in `appDelegate`, but the current class has a `managedObjectContext` property. Are they using the same context?

Comment: I added the data model to my question and made some deeper analyse to the core data records. I get no error message when I run the app. I think you are on the right way to find the error. If I delete a row from the table view the corresponding record is deleted from the entity "Puls" but no record is deleted from the entity "Record". I am missing the code to delete the linked records from "Record". Can you help me on that topic?

Answer (score -1):

In CoreData, first you have to fetch objects that has to be deleted, using NSFetchRequest and NSPredicate.

Then, you should iterate through NSManagedObject and call deleteObject.

Comment: Is there a corresponding "record id" which I can use with NSPredicate to NSFetchRequest the right records using "indexPath.row"or do I have to generate a unique ID by myself?

Comment: First of all why -1? Coredata deleteObject works for NSManagedObject which will be always true. You have not shared data model, I was saying this is how coredata deleteObject works. Next refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215115/deleting-row-from-tableview-and-coredata you will get answer. Read comments